# GetChildAtPoint is not honoring ZOrder

Tags: c#, winforms, z-order

I have a panel control with a label and textbox next to each other. In certain translations the label becomes too long and I'm trying to use `GetChildAtPoint` to determine when the label has become too long and shorten it appropriately (I know there's other/better ways, but I'm somewhat limited in my approach, hence this option).

I've checked the index and the label is 41, while the textbox is 0.
I use `panelControl.GetChildAtPoint(new Point(labelControl.Location.X + labelControl.Width, labelControl.Location.Y))` to try and determine if the label is too long or not, but for some reason, the above code returns the label control instead of the text box.

In debug, `labelControl.Location` = 566, 305 and `textBoxControl.Location` = 716, 290. The label control has a width of 202.

I've seen this approach work in other instances and cannot see any differences here, so I'm really unsure as to why it's not working in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems no problem with your code, please add some testing to see actually size and location change in run time

Eg:

```
    var point = new Point(label1.Location.X + label1.Width,
        label1.Location.Y);
    var p2 = panel1.Controls[1].Location;
    var ctrl = panel1.GetChildAtPoint(point);
    if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Got TextBox";
    }
    else if (ctrl is Label)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Got Label";
    }

    textBox1.Text += string.Format(" {0}:{1} {2}:{3}", point.X, point.Y, p2.X, p2.Y);
```

Comment: The values provided are from debugging/runtime. I'm not sure what else you want me to provide?

Comment: The Locations is the actual data right? Can you also provide calculative data of new Point(labelControl.Location.X + labelControl.Width, labelControl.Location.Y)

Comment: 768,305 (text box width is over 200)

Comment: Seem nothing wrong with your provided data. Is the label still changing size while we get the control?

Comment: Yep, looks like there was some crappy initialization code that was setting visibility to false and even though I'd tried the `GetChildAtPoint` overload with `GetChildAtPointSkip.None`, it was still ignoring it.